# c++ template function error: template-id does not match any template declaration

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code of function template in C++:

```
class UserHelpler{

public:

   template <typename ValueType>
   void createHelper(ValueType& value);
};

template<>
void UserHelpler::createHelper<int>(int* p_user)
{
}
```

When I build it, it shows the following error:

```
error: template-id 'createHelper<int>' for 'void UserHelper::createHelper(int*)'
does not match any template declaration
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that pointers and references are different things. Your template specialization has a signature which is incompatible with the template, as `int*` and `int&` are different types.

Probably, you need

```
createHelper<int>(int& p_user)
```

instead of

```
createHelper<int>(int* p_user)
```

Comment: I changed to createHelper<int>(int& p_user), but it is the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your template declaration requires your parameter to be of **reference** type, but in your specialization you provide a **pointer** instead, which doesn't match. Change your specialization to:

```
template<>
void UserHelpler::createHelper<int>(int& p_user)
```

Or alternatively change your template declaration to:

```
template <typename ValueType>
void createHelper(ValueType* value);
```

Comment: I changed to createHelper<int>(int& p_user), but it is the same error

Comment: Woks for me - [live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecce20bb8c2127eb)